# Exploiting mailto links

Tags: web-application, email, html, validation

Supposing that the user has the power to include any content after `mailto:` snippet, are there any possible security vulnerabilities?

Example:

The user says their email address is *foo*. The link on the page (which is visible to everyone), will be be: `<a href="mailto:foo">foo</a>`.

I'm interested to know if there is a way to exploit this thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if they entered their email as

```
"></a><script>alert("XSS")</script><a href="
```

which (might) be rendered by the application as

`<a href="mailto:"></a><script>alert("XSS")</script><a href="">"></a><script>alert("XSS")</script><a href="</a>`.

giving rise to a [Stored XSS vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

To prevent this, the application should URL percent encode and then HTML encode the email value.

Comment: That's a good point. However, that's an encoding issue. Are there other ways to exploit this case?

Comment: @IonicăBizău perhaps you need to define your scope of "exploit" - this answer shows a way to exploit the HTML.

Comment: @schroeder I'm just curious if there's a way to break the things since the email is not validated.